QT: How to channge button icon on hover event?
I have a custom button class
class MyButton : public QPushButton {
public:
    MyButton(const QString &normalImage, const QString &hoverImage, QSize size, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
            : QPushButton(parent), normalImage(normalImage), hoverImage(hoverImage) {
        setFixedSize(size);
        setFlat(true);
    }

    void setTextColor(const QString& color) {
        QString style = "QPushButton {"
                        "  background-image: url(%1);"
                        "  color: " + color + ";"
                        "  border: none;"
                        "}"
                        "QPushButton:hover {"
                        "  background-image: url(%2);"
                        "}";
        setStyleSheet(style.arg(normalImage, hoverImage));
    }

private:
    QString normalImage;
    QString hoverImage;
};

Also I have to add an icon.png to the image:
MyButton* b1 = new MyButton("Default.png","Hover.png",QSize(140, 40), this);
b1->setText("Text");
b1->setIcon(QIcon("Icon_Dark.png"));

The code is working fine. But how can I change the icon on hover event?
I want to have a methon of MyButton class
void onHoverEvent() {
    this->setIcon(QIcon("Icon_NEW.png"));
}

Icon should be restored to the initial, when mouse is not on the button

You need to override mouse event handler methods. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#enterEvent (I also encourage anyone with time to write a proper answer with actual code.)

Since 5.15 QPushButton supports the icon QSS property, and as far as I know it can be used along with pseudo-states, similarly to what you already do with background-image.

As indicated in the comments, you can use a QMouseEvent. Adding to your class:
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MyButton : public QPushButton {
public:
    MyButton(const QString &normalImage, const QString &hoverImage, QSize size, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
            : QPushButton(parent), normalImage(normalImage), hoverImage(hoverImage) {
        setFixedSize(size);
        setFlat(true);
        setIcon(QIcon("Icon_Dark.png"));
    }

    void setTextColor(const QString& color) {
        QString style = "QPushButton {"
                        "  background-image: url(%1);"
                        "  color: " + color + ";"
                        "  border: none;"
                        "}"
                        "QPushButton:hover {"
                        "  background-image: url(%2);"
                        "}";
        setStyleSheet(style.arg(normalImage, hoverImage));
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
        qreal delta = 3;
        QRect hover_area(delta, delta, width() - 2*delta, height() - 2*delta);
        if(hover_area.contains(event->pos()))
            setIcon(QIcon("Icon_NEW.png"));
        else
            setIcon(QIcon("Icon_Dark.png"));
    }

private:
    QString normalImage;
    QString hoverImage;
};

The only minor inconvenience is that QMouseEvent does not come directly with a hover event. But you can modify the mouseMoveEvent with a slightly smaller area, so that the icon can be reset when the cursor exits the area.
EDIT:
Ha, I stand corrected, this makes it even more convenient:
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MyButton : public QPushButton {
public:
    MyButton(const QString &normalImage, const QString &hoverImage, QSize size, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
            : QPushButton(parent), normalImage(normalImage), hoverImage(hoverImage) {
        setFixedSize(size);
        setFlat(true);
        setIcon(QIcon("Icon_Dark.png"));
    }

    void setTextColor(const QString& color) {
        QString style = "QPushButton {"
                        "  background-image: url(%1);"
                        "  color: " + color + ";"
                        "  border: none;"
                        "}"
                        "QPushButton:hover {"
                        "  background-image: url(%2);"
                        "}";
        setStyleSheet(style.arg(normalImage, hoverImage));
    }

    void enterEvent(QEvent * /*event*/){
        setIcon(QIcon("Icon_NEW.png"));
    }

    void leaveEvent(QEvent * /*event*/){
        setIcon(QIcon("Icon_Dark.png"));
    }

private:
    QString normalImage;
    QString hoverImage;
};

EDIT 2:
The more you know. Following @musicamante 's suggestion, you can split all events coming into your widget and treat them accordingly
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QHoverEvent>

class MyButton : public QPushButton {
public:
    MyButton(const QString &normalImage, const QString &hoverImage, QSize size, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
            : QPushButton(parent), normalImage(normalImage), hoverImage(hoverImage) {
        setFixedSize(size);
        setFlat(true);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover, true);
        setIcon(QIcon("Icon_Dark.png"));
    }

    void setTextColor(const QString& color) {
        QString style = "QPushButton {"
                        "  background-image: url(%1);"
                        "  color: " + color + ";"
                        "  border: none;"
                        "}"
                        "QPushButton:hover {"
                        "  background-image: url(%2);"
                        "}";
        setStyleSheet(style.arg(normalImage, hoverImage));
    }

    bool event(QEvent * e)
    {
        switch(e->type())
        {
        case QEvent::HoverEnter:
            hoverEnter(static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(e));
            break;
        case QEvent::HoverLeave:
            hoverLeave(static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(e));
            break;
        case QEvent::HoverMove:
            hoverMove(static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(e));
            break;
        default:
            notHoverMove(e);
            break;
        }
        return QWidget::event(e);
    }


    void hoverEnter(QHoverEvent * /*event*/){
        if(is_hover_) return;
        setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("Icon_Dark.png"));
        is_hover_ = true;
    }

    void hoverLeave(QHoverEvent * /*event*/){
        if(!is_hover_) return;
        setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("Icon_Dark.png"));
        is_hover_ = false;
    }

    void hoverMove(QHoverEvent * /*event*/){
        if(is_hover_) return;
        setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("Icon_Dark.png"));
        is_hover_ = false;
    }

    void notHoverMove(QEvent * /*event*/){
        QRect button_rect(0,0,height(), width());
        QPoint global_pos = QCursor::pos();
        bool cursor_is_outside = !button_rect.contains(mapFromGlobal(global_pos));

        if(!cursor_is_outside) return;
        else if(cursor_is_outside && !is_hover_) return;

        setIcon(QIcon("Icon_Dark.png"));
        is_hover_ = false;
    }

private:
    bool is_hover_{false};
    QString normalImage;
    QString hoverImage;
};

In my prsonal opinion this actually seems a little overkill, since I failed to produce a situation where a fallback was necessary. But I trust @musicamante may have encountered such situations. The significant changes are the is_hover_ flag, so we do not set the icon unnecessarily and the catch-all bool event(QEvent * e). For the OP: I would really think about if the fallback is necessary, I personally would like to avoid mapping the cursor position for all other events, but that comes down to your usecase.

Qt  enterEvent works only one time. I need to see change on every hover event

mouseMoveEvent is not reliable. I see visualization bugs

A more appropriate solution, assuming that a specific area inside the widget has to be checked, is to set the WA_Hover attribute, and then check for HoverEnter, HoverMove and HoverLeave events. Note that all those events must be checked, as hover events may not always be consistent under certain circumstances. A proper and safer implementation may even consider internal "centralized" functions that would eventually be called from both hover and enter/leave/mouseMove events, possibly using QCursor.pos() as fallback for events that don't provide mouse positions.

mascai, for me it works all the time, but maybe try my other suggestion. @alexmosk25 maybe thats because of the setting of the icon is happening all the time, see my second edit.

@musicamante thanks for your suggestion, but your last point, mapping all enter events I don't think it is necessary. As far as I understand the docs, hoverEnter only extends the call with a painter update event, otherwise it is the same.

@Nyquist That's the default implementation, yes. But their behavior isn't always 100% consistent, as it may depend on focus change, modal/popup windows, etc. I cannot recall the exact situations, but I do remember cases for which a widget received only one of them.
